# How do I display "Only X left Threshold" on my Magento product grid?

Tags: magento

I’m using a custom template I created, and I’m trying to display “Only X left Threshold” set at 1 on the category list(grid) page.

Magento ver. 1.4.1 -

Can anyone help me out?

EDIT

Thanks Alan, solved.

To those who need this for configurable products, here is the code for 'Less than 4 products remaining"

```
<?php if($_product->getTypeId() == "configurable"):
$total = 0;
$ids = $_product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProductIds();  ?>
<ul>
<?php foreach ($ids as $id) :
    $simpleproduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id); ?>

    <li><?php $simpleproduct->getName()." - ".(int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')
                ->loadByProduct($simpleproduct)->getQty(); ?>
    </li>               
    <?php $total = $total + (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($simpleproduct)->getQty(); ?>

<?php endforeach;    ?>
<li><?php if ($total < 4) {
echo ("Only ".$total." Left!");
}?></li>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I tried the code in 1.6.2 every thing is working, only the line beneath not. Any idea?
<?php $simpleproduct->getName()." - ".(int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item') ->loadByProduct($simpleproduct)->getQty(); ?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if($product->getQty() < $some_num)
{
    echo 'Only' . $product->getQty() . ' left';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$qtyStock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty();
if($qtyStock < 10) {
    echo 'Only' . $qtyStock . ' left';
}
```